# Why GCC does not generates assembly code with 1 **imul** instruction for 1 multiplication in C?

Tags: performance, gcc, optimization

I'm checking the assembly code of the following simple program on https://godbolt.org/ with parameters -Wall -m32 using gcc 6.3 and to my surprise the generated assembly code takes three multiplications to perform one multiplication in C as shown below.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<inttypes.h>

int main(void){
     int32_t ax=-854763;
     int32_t bx=586478;
     int64_t cx= (int64_t)ax*bx;
     printf("%lld\n", cx);
}
```

The generated assembly code for the statement **int64_t cx= (int64_t)ax*bx;** is given below. There are two **imull** and one **mull** instructions.

```
movl    -28(%ebp), %eax
movl    %eax, %ecx
movl    %eax, %ebx
sarl    $31, %ebx
movl    -32(%ebp), %eax
cltd
movl    %ebx, %edi
imull   %eax, %edi
movl    %edx, %esi
imull   %ecx, %esi
addl    %edi, %esi
mull    %ecx
leal    (%esi,%edx), %ecx
movl    %ecx, %edx
movl    %eax, -40(%ebp)
movl    %edx, -36(%ebp)
movl    %eax, -40(%ebp)
movl    %edx, -36(%ebp)`
```

Is it possible to enforce the gcc compiler/assembler to do it with just one multiplication without using inline assembly? Because in the original code I have to perform many such multiplications within a statement and in different statements.

Why the compiler does not perform it with one **imul** instruction? I have also checked the different versions of the gcc on https://godbolt.org/ but the result is same three multiplication instruction.

Comment: This question needs more specific constraints. What language, what exact data types, do the resulting series of integers need to conform to some interface (say, Java List<>, or indexable with C [] array indexing).

Comment: @hyde: I thought that may be this is independent of the language and I am using C language array.

Comment: If you want to splice several arrays together, that's going to get complex. And in C you can't really hide that complexity, either. In C you can try to play around with realloc, but chances are it will just make things a bit slower with little to no actual memory benefit.

Comment: @hyde what about static arrays in C? In case that size of arrays are small enough to be easily accommodated in cache.

Comment: Reallocating memory and copying will get messy.  If you can calculate the ultimate size of the answer, allocate that, then use that as your accumulator.

Comment: From the question it looks like the result array has dynamic length. Also, why would you care about memory savings (which you ask about in the question itself) if you have small static arrays? Now your question seems even more unclear... :)

Comment: If I understand correctly, just allocate the final array, and do the additions into it. If you need result in a C array, you need to hav the array. If you don't need result in array, write a function which takes the input arrays and index in result array, and returns result value for that index.